# Shared Element transition crash on Samsung device running Android 8.0

Tags: android, kotlin, samsung-mobile, android-transitions, shared-element-transition

I've a weird crash, apparently unfixable happening on Samsung devices only running Android 8.0.

I've a recyclerView populated in a Fragment that it's launching an Activity.

Here is my ItemHolder layout

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/table_card_header_size"
android:transitionName="@string/team_profile_transition"
android:id="@+id/tableRowMainContainer"
android:background="@drawable/rounded_rect_top"
> ...
```

Here's is my Intent to the activity with the shared element

```
private val teamProfileOnClick = View.OnClickListener { v ->
    val teamContainer = v.findViewById<FrameLayout>(R.id.tableRowMainContainer)
    val tag = v.tag as TableRow
    val intent = Intent(context, TeamProfileActivity::class.java)
    intent.putExtra(TeamProfileActivity.TEAM_ID_PROFILE, tag.teamId)
    intent.putExtra(TeamProfileActivity.TEAM_NAME, tag.team.name)
    intent.putExtra(TeamProfileActivity.TEAM_COMPETITION_ID, tableCompetitionId)
    intent.putExtra(TeamProfileActivity.TEAM_TYPE, tag.team.teamType)

    val options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(context as Activity,
            teamContainer,
            ViewCompat.getTransitionName(teamContainer))
    context.startActivity(intent, options.toBundle())
}
```

And here is the layout of the destination activity

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tool="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/cardview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:transitionName="@string/team_profile_transition"
app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
> ...
```

Here is the crash log

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at android.app.ActivityTransitionCoordinator.setSharedElementState (ActivityTransitionCoordinator.java:553)
  at android.app.ActivityTransitionCoordinator.setSharedElementState (ActivityTransitionCoordinator.java:653)
  at android.app.EnterTransitionCoordinator.startSharedElementTransition (EnterTransitionCoordinator.java:428)
  at android.app.EnterTransitionCoordinator.-wrap4 (Unknown Source)
  at android.app.EnterTransitionCoordinator$3.lambda$-android_app_EnterTransitionCoordinator$3_18867 (EnterTransitionCoordinator.java:492)
  at android.app.-$Lambda$CsyQO--8YdRe5wlajUCi-L98enA$1.$m$0 (Unknown Source:8)
  at android.app.-$Lambda$CsyQO--8YdRe5wlajUCi-L98enA$1.run (Unknown Source)
  at android.app.ActivityTransitionCoordinator.startTransition (ActivityTransitionCoordinator.java:902)
  at android.app.EnterTransitionCoordinator$3.lambda$-android_app_EnterTransitionCoordinator$3_18819 (EnterTransitionCoordinator.java:491)
  at android.app.-$Lambda$CsyQO--8YdRe5wlajUCi-L98enA$2.$m$0 (Unknown Source:8)
  at android.app.-$Lambda$CsyQO--8YdRe5wlajUCi-L98enA$2.run (Unknown Source)
  at com.android.internal.view.OneShotPreDrawListener.onPreDraw (OneShotPreDrawListener.java:78)
  at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw (ViewTreeObserver.java:1045)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals (ViewRootImpl.java:2800)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal (ViewRootImpl.java:1779)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run (ViewRootImpl.java:7810)
  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:911)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:723)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:658)
  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:897)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:789)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:98)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6938)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:327)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I have the same

Comment: How did you end up resolving this?

Comment: Yes, I did. Please check my solution

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found is the following : 
Freeze/unfreeze  the recyclerView when opening the shared element :

```
 override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    tableCardStack.isLayoutFrozen = true
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    tableCardStack.isLayoutFrozen = false
}
```

What I've noticed was that the view I was animating was not animating back to the right position. So I thought to freeze the layout. I know it's not the best solution but I couldn't find anything better

Answer (score 0):

Looks like certain Samsung devices don't check if the views parent is `null` which can happen in some edge cases. You can prevent this crash from happening by removing the views without parents from the transition. This is done by adding a `SharedElementCallback` to your activity and overwriting `onSharedElementEnd` and/or `onSharedElementStart` (depending on whether its your Enter or Exit transition that is crashing) and then finding and removing the views like this:

```
activity.setEnterSharedElementCallback(object : SharedElementCallback() {

    override fun onSharedElementStart(sharedElementNames: MutableList<String>?, sharedElements: MutableList<View>?, sharedElementSnapshots: MutableList<View>?) {
        sharedElements?.removeAll(sharedElements.filter { it.parent == null })
        super.onSharedElementStart(sharedElementNames, sharedElements, sharedElementSnapshots)
    }

    override fun onSharedElementEnd(sharedElementNames: MutableList<String>?, sharedElements: MutableList<View>?, sharedElementSnapshots: MutableList<View>?) {
        sharedElements?.removeAll(sharedElements.filter { it.parent == null })
        super.onSharedElementEnd(sharedElementNames, sharedElements, sharedElementSnapshots)
    }
}
```

Be aware that this does not remove the root cause of the crash, only prevents it from happening by not animating the view without a parent.